# How Nodejs interact with Server (Local-Machine which is window 10)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, mongodb

I want to know how Nodejs Server Interact with Local Machine. Like I want to capture some task i.e

```
Thread Level
CPU Cycle
Socket Level
IO
```

Anyone Helps will be appreciated

Comment: have you considered [reading](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/os.html) [any](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/net.html) [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/process.html) at all?

Comment: No. Actually I don't get any documentation for solving these 4 Task

Comment: what tasks? you've listed 4 points, none of which is a "task" that needs "solving" - hmmm, just realised ... hang on, will post the standard response in a second

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @JaromandaX see I know very well about the standard response. I am just here for asking that how I can do this. I am not writing my problem sets.

Comment: right, how you can do what? Perhaps you need to rewrite your question in a way that is a lot less vague

Answer (score 0):

All the Documentation is done From here. So have to look and try to get exactly what you want from here ['Documentation'](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/os.html/)